# How to fill background color of excel rows with Python?

Tags: python, excel, background-color

I' m beginner in Python.

1. I have a excel file.

   ```
   |  Name   |  Reg Date  |
   |Annie    | 2021-07-01 |
   |Billy    | 2021-07-02 |
   |Cat      | 2021-07-03 |
   |David    | 2021-07-04 |
   |Eric     | 2021-07-04 |
   |Annie    | 2021-07-01 |
   |Bob      | 2021-07-05 |
   |David    | 2021-07-04 |
   ```
2. I found duplicate rows in excel.

   Code:

   ```
   import openpyxl as xl

   import pandas as pd

   import numpy as np

   dt = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/Student.xlsx') 
   dt['Duplicate'] = dt.duplicated()
   DuplicateRows=[dt.duplicated(['Name', 'Reg Date'], keep=False)]

   print(DuplicateRows)
   ```

   Output:

   ```
        Name       Reg Date    Duplicate
    1   Annie     2021-07-01     False
    6   Annie     2021-07-01     True
    4   David     2021-07-04     False 
    8   David     2021-07-04     True
   ```
3. Above I have two questions... Please teach me.

   Q1: How to update `Duplicate` value from `False` to `True`?

   Q2: When `Duplicate` is `True`, how to fill background color of rows save in `Student.xlsx`?

Comment: For Q1 - are you trying interchange True and False for ALL rows in the `Duplicate` column or only for Annie and David? Is Q2 coloring for 'True` rows before or after you made the True/False interchange?

Comment: Q1: Only for Annie to David. Q2: After made True/False interchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `duplicated()` function itself doesn't have a way to interchange True and False. You can use a NOT operator (`~`) to so this. Also, used `PatternFill` to color the relevant rows and write to `student.xlsx`. Please refer to below code.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl import Workbook

dt = pd.read_excel("myinput.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
dt['Duplicate'] = dt.duplicated()
dt['Duplicate'] = ~dt[dt.duplicated(['Name', 'Reg Date'], keep=False)].Duplicate
dt['Duplicate'] = dt['Duplicate'].replace(np.nan, False)

print(dt)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Write heading
for i in range(0, dt.shape[1]):
    cell_ref = ws.cell(row=1, column=i+1)
    cell_ref.value = dt.columns[i-1]

#Write and colot data rows
for row in range(dt.shape[0]):
    for col in range(dt.shape[1]):
        print(row, col, dt.iat[row, col])
        ws.cell(row+2,col+1).value = str(dt.iat[row, col])
        if dt.iat[row, 2] == True:
            ws.cell(row+2,col+1).fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFD970', end_color='FFD970', fill_type="solid")  # change hex code to change color

wb.save('student.xlsx')
```

**Output sheet**

[image]

**Updated Req**

Hi - Please find below the updated code. This will read the data from `Student.xlsx` Sheet1 and update Sheet2 with the updated colored sheet. If there is NO sheet by that name, it will error out. If there is data in those specific cells in Sheet2, that data will be overwritten, not any other data. Only `Name` and `Reg Date` will be written. Post writing to the excel sheet, the dataframe `dt`'s `Duplicate` column will also be deleted and will only contain the other two columns. Hope this is clear and is what you are looking for...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl import load_workbook

dt = pd.read_excel("Student.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
dt['Duplicate'] = dt.duplicated()
dt['Duplicate'] = ~dt[dt.duplicated(['Name', 'Reg Date'], keep=False)].Duplicate
dt['Duplicate'] = dt['Duplicate'].replace(np.nan, False)

wb = load_workbook("Student.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet2']  # Make sure this sheet exists, else, it will give an error

#Write Heading
for i in range(0, dt.shape[1]-1):
    ws.cell(row = 1, column = i+1).value = dt.columns[i]

#Write Data
for row in range(dt.shape[0]):
    for col in range(dt.shape[1] - 1):
        print(row, col, dt.iat[row, col])
        ws.cell(row+2,col+1).value = str(dt.iat[row, col])
        if dt.iat[row, 2] == True:
            ws.cell(row+2,col+1).fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFD970', end_color='FFD970', fill_type="solid")  # used hex code for brown color

wb.save("Student.xlsx")

dt = dt.drop(['Duplicate'], axis=1, inplace=True) # Finally remove the column Duplicated, in case you want to use it
print(dt)
```

**Output Excel**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. If I do not create 'Duplicate' column...

Comment: dt = pd.read_excel("myinput.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
dt = dt[dt.duplicated(['Name', 'Reg Date'], keep=False)] 

Q1: How can use 'Openyxl' to find and fill background for duplicate record? Q2: Can use 'xl.load_workbook' to fill background color ?

Comment: Hi @CHL - Are you saying that you want to create create file with only `Name` and `Reg Date`? Is that the ask?

Comment: You want to use `load_workbook()` because you want to add the updated table to an existing sheet specified in load_workbook()? Is that the other requirement?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create create file with only Name and Reg Date? Is that the ask? <<<I'm sorry ENG is not my first language. Yes! you get my ask point

Comment: You want to use load_workbook() because you want to add the updated table to an existing sheet specified in load_workbook()? Is that the other requirement?<<<Haha! I want to update duplicate record only, you get me ask point again , If use ''Openyxl' module is it re-write excel all content?

Comment: I have added the new code as your requirement. Hope that works. If there is data in a specific cell that you are writing to, that data will be deleted, no other impact to other cells or worksheets